# BigCartel add Products via External Website

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, bigcartel

i used to add products from my website to bigcartel via a standard html link and url parameters: (i.e. http://poleit.bigcartel.com/cart?cart%5Badd%5D%5Bid%5D=88038046)

since bigcartel themself are just sending a POST to the cart including the values `cart[add][id]` it worked fine and the products were added to the cart on my bigcartel shopping page.

but it is no longer working, and i can't tell why. Anybody else got the same problem right now? Did Bigcartel change anything in their parameters or urls to POST to?

It still works on the bigcartel shop page itself - here is what gets posted:

```
URL:http://poleit.bigcartel.com/cart
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:151.101.1.211:80
Referrer Policy:origin
```

and form data is:

```
utf8:✓
cart[add][id]:147031078
submit:
```

my link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://poleit.bigcartel.com/cart?cart%5Badd%5D%5Bid%5D=88038046" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'bigcartel','right=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0'); return false;" class="link link-add js_link-to-big animated fadeIn">add to cart</a>
```

Thank you for your help!
here are the links:

http://poleit.net

http://poleit.net/product/lazyboy-green/

http://poleit.bigcartel.com